# Showing time when hovering on input range

Tags: javascript, html, video

You know that thing on youtube, when you hover on a certain part of seek slider, it shows you a timecode that you're hovering on. I want to grab that value and display it in a title attribute of this slider. How can I do it?

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" title="javascript:hoverTimeFunction()"/>
```

Here's what I need: [image]
You see, that video current time is *2:04* but I'm hovering on *3:27* timecode and it shows me a *3:27* value in title without dragging the thumb. But the thing is that I need to display a video time, not just slider value. I'm getting the time using this function:

```js
seekSlider = document.getElementById("seekSlider");

function videoTimeUpdate(){
"use strict";
  var timeInterval = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
  seekSlider.value = timeInterval;
  var currentMinutes = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
  var currentSeconds = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - currentMinutes * 60);
  var durationMinutes = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
  var durationSeconds = Math.floor(vid.duration - durationMinutes * 60);
  if(currentSeconds < 10) {currentSeconds = "0"+ currentSeconds;}
  if(durationSeconds < 10) {durationSeconds = "0"+ durationSeconds;}
  if(currentMinutes < 10) {currentMinutes = "0"+ currentMinutes;}
  if(durationMinutes < 10) {durationMinutes = "0"+ durationMinutes;}
    currentTime.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds; 
  vidDuration.innerHTML = durationMinutes + ":" + durationSeconds;
}
```

And by the way, I need a solution without using jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pure javascript + css solution. There's only one problem: unless you make the slider larger, the number displayed won't be the actual value it's gonna set on the slider if you click. This is because the coordinate at which the mouse is located doesn't correspond to what value the slider will set at that position.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var slidertitle = document.getElementById("slidertitle");

var sliderOffsetX = slider.getBoundingClientRect().left - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var sliderOffsetY = slider.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

var sliderWidth = slider.offsetWidth - 1;

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var currentMouseXPos = (event.clientX + window.pageXOffset) - sliderOffsetX;
  var sliderValAtPos = Math.round(currentMouseXPos / sliderWidth * 100 + 1);
  // this...
  if(sliderValAtPos < 0) sliderValAtPos = 0;
  // ... and this are to make it easier to hover on the "0" and "100" positions
  if(sliderValAtPos > 100) sliderValAtPos = 100;
  slidertitle.innerHTML = sliderValAtPos;
  slidertitle.style.top = sliderOffsetY - 15 + 'px';
  slidertitle.style.left = currentMouseXPos + 'px';
});
```

```css
#slider {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#slidertitle {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#container:hover > #slidertitle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" id="slider"/>
  <span id="slidertitle"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read my edit, it's important.

Comment: Oh snap. That's a shame. But anyway, who cares? I'm just making a video player look cooler.

Comment: I think I have an ugly solution to always show the right value but I can't try it right now.

Comment: Is my solution better? Function name `sliderHoverValue` on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVxBOJ)

Comment: Well it seems pretty accurate (also because the slider is larger), but most of the times it shows 1 second less than the actual value, so maybe you should subtract 1 from the final number. But sometimes it's 2 seconds off.

Comment: Then what method of `Math` will you suggest to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143761/discussion-between-eugen-eray-and-nonzaprej).

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the `input` event on the slider to change the title attribute.

Here is an example.

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

// set the initial value
slider.title = slider.value;

// add listener to input event
slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
 e.target.title = e.target.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" title="" />
```

Comment: Updated the question.